# moq: When using Setup(), how is equality of method parameters determined?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using the `Setup()` method to set up the behaviour of a mocked instance of an interface.

The method I'm setting up (let's call it `DoSomething()`) accepts an instance of a class (let's call the class `Foo`).

```
Foo foo = // Existing foo instance
Mock<IMyInterface> mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(foo)).Returns(1);
```

The problem I'm having is that when I use the mock, it never matches the setup, so never returns 1.

Can anyone help? How does Moq determine whether the parameters provided to a set up method are equal or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to my question is that Moq uses `.Equals` to determine whether parameters to set up methods are equal.

Comment: R# is a great help here, as it can automatically generate Equals method for your class.

Comment: Note that it appears to use `.Equals(object)` rather than any `.Equals(T)` (if your class implements `IEquatable<T>`)

Answer (score 6):

For a slightly more detailed answer, Moq uses the [`ConstantMatcher`](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/v4.13.1/src/Moq/Matchers/ConstantMatcher.cs) (link is to current latest version 4.13.1). The implementation of that matcher is

1. Use `object.Equals`
2. If `object.Equals` failed and value implements `IEnumerable` use `SequenceEqual<object>` (which uses `object.Equals` for each element)
3. If both of the above failed return `false`

Comment: This is very helpful to know, in fact it's better than the accepted answer. It means that lists that contain the same values also works as a match. Thank you.