# Unit Testing: Mocking returning null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, nsubstitute

I have done this many times with the same, scenario but this time it is failing and I am not able to figure out the reason, please help me out.

Below is my code, I have tried with both Moq, and NSubsitute, but for both, returns is returning `null` but it should return the json, I am putting inside, I have done the same in previous projects as well, but never faced such an issue, my mind totally not working.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public string myOrder(List<Order> order);       
}
```

### Target Class

```
public class funcMyFunctionApp
{
    private readonly IMyInterface myInterface;
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public funcMyFunctionApp(IMyInterface _myInterface)
    {
        myInterface = _myInterface;
    }

    [FunctionName("func1")]
    public IActionResult func1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post",Route = "func1")] string jsoninput)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsoninput))
            {
                return new OkObjectResult(myInterface.myOrder(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(jsoninput)));
            }
            else
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Bad Order");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            if(ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
            }
            return new BadRequestObjectResult("Bad Order");
        }
    }
}
```

### Test Fixture

```
public void shouldReturnOkObjectResultifInputisValid()
{
    string ValidJson1 = @"[
        {
          ""CreatedBy"":""test@test.org"",
          ""OrderNo"":""Pizz111"",
          ""Amount"":""10$"",
        }
    ]";
    string ValidOutputJson1 = @"{
        ""OrderNo"": ""808098"",
        ""Item"": ""Pizza""
    }";
    Mock<IMyInterface> myInterfaceMock =new Mock<IMyInterface>();
    IMyInterface myInterfaceSubsititueMock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
    var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(ValidJson1);
    myInterfaceMock.Setup(m=>m.myOrder(input)).Returns(ValidOutputJson1);
    
    //Local Arrange
    myInterfaceSubsititueMock.myOrder(ValidJson1).Returns(ValidOutputJson1);
    funcMyFunctionApp funcRequest = new funcMyFunctionApp(myInterfaceMock.Object);
    
    // Act
    var result = funcRequest.func1(ValidJson1);
    
    // Assert
    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        Assert.That((((OkObjectResult)result).Value as string), Is.EqualTo(ValidOutputJson1));
    });
}
```

I am expecting that it should return the string provided under `Returns`

Comment: Please format your code properly and split it into separate blocks, which will make it easier to read and get a better overview.

Comment: It ought to be possible to reduce the problem to a smaller repro. Often when you do that, you'll find the solution as part of the process. Please consult the site's official guide to making a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance. Feel free to ping me once you've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(jsoninput)` is not the same as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(ValidJson1)`.

In case of Moq, the library uses [`object.Equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291760/moq-when-using-setup-how-is-equality-of-method-parameters-determined) to determine whether the formal and actual parameters are the same. In other words it performs reference check for reference types. That's why even though your two `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method calls return the same collection, but they will be two different List instances.

In order to solve your problem use `It.IsAny<List<Order>>()` in your `Setup` call:

```
myInterfaceMock
   .Setup(m=>m.myOrder(It.IsAny<List<Order>>()))
   .Returns(ValidOutputJson1);
```

---

Dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dYcKk6

---

**UPDATE #1**

As it was suggested by Neil you can further restrict your `Setup`. The `It.IsAny` does not care about formal and actual parameters equality. Rather than it checks only data type.

If you want to make sure that the formal and actual collection parameters are the same you can utilize `It.Is`:

```
// If ordering does not matter
.Setup(m=>m.myOrder(It.Is<List<Order>>(actual => input.All(actual.Contains))))
//OR
.Setup(m=>m.myOrder(It.Is<List<Order>>(actual => actual.All(input.Contains))))

// If ordering matters
.Setup(m=>m.myOrder(It.Is<List<Order>>(actual => input.SequenceEqual(actual))))
// OR
.Setup(m=>m.myOrder(It.Is<List<Order>>(actual => actual.SequenceEqual(input))))
```

To make this work `Order` must be either a `record` or implement the `IEquatable` interface.

Comment: Even better would be to use `It.Is` and do a string comparison between the expected and the actual, to make sure it's exactly what is expected.

Comment: @Neil Good point, but `myOrder` anticipates a `List<Order>` not a `string`. Let me amend later my answer to include `It.Is` as well.